# Trying to create program that can follow DeviantArt's download button

Tags: c#, http

I've been tinkering together a program that lets me bulk-download image galleries around the net, as I like to collect artwork from video games and such. I've been trying to adapt it to be able to download from DeviantArt, and I have it working for everything except when I try to get it to follow the download button that accompanies many images on there. I've done everything I can think of to try and re-create a real web request, but so far all I get in the response is an HTML page that redirects back to the main image page. Here's how I'm currently trying to do it:

```
                HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(im.Groups[1].Value);
                req.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 5;
                req.Method = "HEAD";
                req.Accept = "*/*";
                req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36";
                req.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch");
                req.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
                req.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
                req.Referer = m.Value;
                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.lastSetCookie))
                {
                    CookieContainer cc = new CookieContainer();
                    string[] cookie_sections = this.lastSetCookie.Split(';');
                    Dictionary<String, String> cookie_arge = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    foreach(String cookie_section in cookie_sections)
                    {
                        cookie_arge.Add(cookie_section.Split('=')[0].Trim(), cookie_section.Split('=')[1].Trim());
                    }
                    cc.Add(new Uri("http://deviantart.com"), new Cookie("userinfo",cookie_arge["userinfo"]));
                }

                HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
                image_url = res.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri;
                res.Close();
```

As you can see, I create a request, make sure it allows some redirects, and then manually set some header fields that I verified are being sent by a regular chrome browser. The referer being sent is the image's main page. The next bit checks a variable that stores the cookie received from the server when the image's page was requested, then sets those cookies on the new request. Deviantart does some session magick, so preserving the cookies is important. Then the request is sent, and an HTML page with javascript and meta tag redirects back to the image page is returned. Any ideas for things to try?

Comment: Maybe you can compare a real request with your request in wireshark.

Comment: Did you tried to run fiddler and sniff your request?

Comment: Have you tried to use Selenium for this?

Comment: I've been using chrome extensions to inspect my requests. A more objective analysis of the data is a good idea, I'll give that a shot. I have also not hear of Selenium, I'll look into that.